# Can any one understand this "Historical share of calls by incident type for each station by time blocks."

Tags: grammar

Historical share of calls by incident type  for each station by time blocks

Comment: Not without more context.

Comment: But it's probably looking for something like this: https://www.nfpa.org/News-and-Research/Data-research-and-tools/Emergency-Responders/Fire-department-calls

Answer (score 1):

[Time] Historical share of [phone] calls [arranged] by type-of-incident for each station [arranged] by time [periods or] blocks

Arranged can also be *Broken down by* in order to describe the sorting for statistical purposes.

Yes, more context is essential to be sure of any interpretation.